# cannot import pypi package after install

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pypi, virtualenvwrapper

I distribute a pypi package and now I cannot import it at all for some reason, it worked in the past.

After I run `pip install mypackage` and navigate to the place in my virtualenv where it is... (`'site-packages/g_recaptcha`') I see these files...

```
__init__.py   models.pyc  tests.pyc              views.py
__init__.pyc  templates/  validate_recaptcha.py  views.pyc
models.py     tests.py    validate_recaptcha.py
```

but when I go into python and try

```
from g_recaptcha import validate_recaptcha
```

I get the error

```
>>> from g_recaptcha import validate_recaptcha
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name validate_recaptcha
```

I can, however, run `import g_recaptcha` and when I do that and then run help I get this...

```
Help on package g_recaptcha:

NAME
    g_recaptcha

FILE
    /Users/Jeff/Development/python/g_recaptcha/__init__.py

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    g_recaptcha (package)
    manage
    project (package)
    setup
```

EDIT: I just noticed that it is trying to use my local version for some reason. Once upon a time I installed it local to test if it builded properly. I tried uninstalling, reinstalling with no difference

I also tried installing with `--no-cache-dir` option which had no difference

EDIT2:

if I go to system python:

this works:

```
pip install -e /path/to/django-g-recaptcha
```

this does not:

```
pip install django-g-recaptcha
pip install --no-cache-dir django-g-recaptcha
```

If I try from my virtualenv (virtualenvwrapper):

NOTHING WORKS

If I ssh into a remote machine:

EVERYTHING WORKS

Comment: When you invoked `python`, was your working directory `/Users/Jeff/Development/python`?

Comment: it was not, I was in another subdirectory of Development